# Git rm all that says "deleted by us" during a merge

Tags: git

During a merge, sometimes there are within unmerged paths, there will be multiple files which says "deleted by us". If I want to keep them deleted, each one needs `git rm` applied.

How do I do that with one command instead of using `git rm` on each file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use other Linux tools! `git status --porcelain` is suited to be easily manipulated, and "DU" is equivalent to "deleted by us".

`git status --porcelain | grep "DU" | cut -c4- | xargs git rm`

> `--porcelain[=<version>]`
>
> Give the output in an easy-to-parse format for scripts. This is similar to the short output, but will remain stable across Git versions and regardless of user configuration.

Comment: Hmm..not that familiar with the command. I tried `git status | grep -rl "deleted by us" | xargs git rm" doesn't quite work.

Comment: The pipeline works as-is, on all the files in the current directory and subdirectories. I expanded my reply.

Comment: Did porcelain change? Deleted by us was not in the output, so I had to use this instead: `git status --porcelain | grep "DU" | cut -c4- | xargs git rm`

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get j4nw's answer to work for me (using `git bash` in windows), so here's how I modified it for my purposes using SED: I specifically wanted to isolate the "deleted by user" lines designed by DU in the `git status --porcelain` output.

```
    git status --porcelain | sed -n -e '/^DU <dev_directory>/p' | sed 's/DU <dev_directory>/./' | xargs git rm
```

`<dev_directory>` is the root folder that all of my offending files were in. For example, here's one of the lines output from `git status --porcelain`:

```
    DU dev/src/A/filename
```